# Comparing performance of models fitted across time series with different frequencies

Tags: time-series, model-evaluation

I have a time series with observations over the span of minutes, hours or even days. I'm interested in knowing if is better to use a daily, weekly or monthly version of the original time series, which I can produce by aggregating the original values.

In synthesis, 5 models were fitted over the 3 time series (daily, weekly and monthly) and the errors should be compared. Because of aggregation, monthly model predictions have a large magnitude compared to daily and weekly, so the errors are much bigger, despite that monthly models could be better.

**Which would be a good approach to compare different magnitude errors?**

### EDIT

I could normalize the series by its maximum in the training set, or normalize the errors. The first makes sense to me, but not the later.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the data you are forecasting? The answer on your question might depend on the nature of the data. It is also not quite clear to me, which models you have already estimated. Did you mean in the 2 paragraph that you aggregated someway high-frequency intraday data into daily, weekly and monthly data? Have you estimated autoregressive models or you alse use external regressors? By the way, have you tried $MIDAS$ (**Mi**xed **Da**ta **S**ampling) regression models? They are able to use efficiently high-frequency data (external regressors and autoregressiv

Comment: You are right about paragraph 2. I have autoregressions and models with additional regressors. The 5 models are: arima, prophet, elastic net, random forest and prophet-xgboost. I haven't heard about MIDAS, so I definitely will give a look to it.